# What's wrong with my code? How can I fix it? C++

Tags: c++

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    using namespace std;

    int main(){

    vector<string> row(7, "0");
    char input;
    int pos;

    cin >> input;
    cin >> pos;

    if(input == 'X')
        row[pos] = '1';

    //ascii value of 1 is 49

    if(row[pos] - 49 == 0)
        cout << "Correct";

    return 0;
    }
```

I keep getting an error at my last `if` statement.  Any ideas why it's not working, and how I can fix it?  By the way, `row` **has** to be a string vector, I can't make it any other type.

I want `row[pos]` to take the character in `row` at the position `pos`

Comment: You forgot to tell us which error you are getting. This should be part of the title, your current title is very generic.

Comment: i think the title does not describe nothing usefull. what kind of error do you wanna solve

Answer (score 4):

You can't subtract integers and strings.

Use characters and conversion to int:

```
char ch = row[pos][0];
int asciiCode = (int)ch;
if (asciiCode == 49) {
   cout << "Correct";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you want to compare the first letter of the case, in which case you have two options:

```
if(row[pos][0] - 49 == 0)
        cout << "Correct";
```

or

```
if(*row[pos].c_str() - 49 == 0)
        cout << "Correct";
```

It's illegal to attempt to substract an `int` from a `std::string`.

`row[pos]` is a string because `row` is a `vector` of `strings`. If you want `row` to be a `string` and `row[pos]` to be a `char`, declare row as a string. Or perhaps you meant for row to be a vector of `chars`.

Comment: Not the first letter in the row, but the letter at the position pos that the user indicates.

Comment: @user1038665 in which string. row is a vector of strings, not a single string.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the last if-statement is that `row[pos]` is of type `string`. So you can't subtract 49 from it. What you want is the first character of the string:

```
if(row[pos][0] - 49 == 0)
```

It's arguably more readable to do this instead:

```
if(row[pos][0] - '1' == 0)
```

Comment: Why is row[pos] a string and not a char?  I don't want the first position, I want the position of the number that the user entered, that's why I did row[pos]

Comment: `row` is a vector of strings. `row[pos]` gives you the `pos'th` string in that vector. All your strings are only 1 character long. And to access it you need the extra `[0]` to access that character.

Comment: So, let's say pos = 5. row[pos][0] takes the character at position 5 in the vector row?

Comment: It will take the first character of the string at index 5.